# Disable Modal Popup if Form is not Valid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have an MVC 5 form that submits through jquery and submits the form to the HTTPPost method on the controller.  That all works fine but I need it to validate the form.  Right now it will show the validation summary on the page with the controls but the screen overlay comes on but doesn't display the popup.  So I think its halfway working.  I just don't want it to overlay the screen and I don't want the popup to display if the form is not valid.  How can I achieve this?

Form cshtml

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ballotForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BallotViewModel, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "BallotViewModel" } })

    <table class="col-sm-12">
        <tr>
            <td>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-submit" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true"></span> Submit
                </button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('#ballotForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        var isValid = $('#ballotForm').valid();
        console.log(isValid);
        if (isValid)
        {

        e.preventDefault();

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('target');

        $.post(url, data)
            .done(function (response, status, jqxhr) {

                $('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                    var modal = $(this);
                    console.log(modal);
                    modal.find('.modal-content').html(response);
                    console.log(response);
                });
                $('#modal-container').modal('show');

            })
            .fail(function (jqxhr, status, error) { });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I have used the following library to accomplish validation with bootstrap.
https://github.com/johnnyreilly/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native

Comment: that did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by adding the following snippet above my current jquery code.

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnBallotFormSubmit").click(function () {
        var ValidStatus = $("#ballotForm").valid();
        console.log(ValidStatus);
    if (ValidStatus == false) {
        return false;
    }
});
});
```